# Json Parsing from API With Dicts

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, web-scraping, python-requests

I am writing a piece of code to retrieve certain information from the League of Legends api.

I have everything working fine and printing to my console, I have even managed to access the data and print off only the information that I need, the only issue is there are 299 values which I would like printed off and I can only manage to print one at a time. This would obviously be the worst way to sort through it as it would take forever to write the program. I have spent over 3 days researching and watching videos with no success so far.

Below is the code I currently have (minus imports).

```
url =('https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/league/v4/challengerleagues/by- 
queue/RANKED_SOLO_5x5?api_key=RGAPI-b5187110-2f16-48b4-8b0c-938ae5bddccb')
r = requests.get(url)
response_dict = r.json()
print(response_dict['entries'][0]['summonerName'])
print(response_dict['entries'][1]['summonerName'])
```

When I attempt to index entries like '[0:299]' I get the following error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the index, that'll print them all out

```
for i in range(300):
    print(response_dict['entries'][i]['summonerName'])
```

When you use `response_dict['entries'][M:N]`

You create a new list of dictionaries that have to be extracted before you can reference `['summonerName']` directly

If you `print(response_dict['entries'][0:3])`

You'll see what I mean

Comment: wow. I was so close earlier, I had a for loop in range but didnt have the parameter of 300 set. sigh. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would simply convert the list of dictionaries within entries into a dataframe. You have all the info nicely organised and can access specific items easily including your column for `summonerName` .

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json
import pandas as pd
#url = yourURL
res = requests.get(url, headers = {'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('p').text)
df = pd.DataFrame(data['entries'])
print(df)
```